# The remote name could not be resolved: 'login.salesforce.com'

Tags: single-sign-on

I create a web application in which Salesforce SSO with OAuth is used.

I used Salesforce Toolkit SDK .net to perform Webserver authentication.
`WebServerAsync` throws following error.

> An error occurred while sending the request.The remote name could not
>   be resolved: 'login.salesforce.com'

[image]

This error is only generating at production server, localhost working properly.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'it works with localhost'?